# Can JBoss Drools be used to assign credit for sales transactions in mass?

Tags: stored-procedures, data-warehouse, drools

I am involved in projects where we frequently use SQL to hit a data warehouse and further crunch the numbers depending on certain rules. These rules are currently implemented via stored procedures or something similar.

I have not used Drools or been exposed to it.

I am particularly interested in if it is possible to use it to assign credit for sales transactions, in mass.

If there are examples of this usage, please let me know.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drools is a Rete rules engine.  I don't see what it has to do with mass updates of persistent data.

It can house the rules that determine when assigning that credit is correct, but it would not be the tool for performing the update.  That's a database issue.

It's not the only choice for executing those rules.  You might also choose to do it using database triggers that are executed ON INSERT/UPDATE.

UPDATE: Drools and stored procs are mutually exclusive.  One's a server side technology, the other runs in the database.  You have to decide where you what to execute your business logic.

The problem with a stored proc is that it ties you to that database vendor and it executes on database events, like BEFORE or AFTER INSERT or UPDATE.  It won't know about your business events, such as "the rules tell me that this individual qualifies for a credit", unless you embed it in stored proc code.

If you do that, you don't need Drools.  The two are mutually exclusive or redundant.

Comment: I am aware that Drools is not a database server in itself. What I am wondering is if Drools is intended to operate on several records in a batch, rather than one record per run like a diagnostics app.

Comment: Drools doesn't know anything about batch; rules are executed on the record data, one at a time.  So is your batch - you write a block of records to the server, one at a time.  So your batch process will loop over each record, call Drools to determine whether or not to apply the credit, modify the record data as needed, then send the record to the database.

Comment: From what you are saying, once a commission rate is determined (say by a rule,) the arithmetic to calculate the commission is not a job for Drools, but for the system receiving that commission rate from Drools such as a stored procedure that is triggered by an updated table receiving the commission rate?

Comment: Okay, thanks. Your explanation makes things much clearer! I assume that Drools needs all pertinent information on hand at "rule-time" and has no way of collecting more information on its own. That means it probably needs to have a single source of data too.

Comment: Response to update: So Drools really is a business logic layer. I will have to really think about its implementation and how we can use it. Thanks for your insight.

Answer (score 2):

Drools is used a lot to assign credit, so I believe you'll find it very useful to write your credit rules there (to change them between releases or even let the credit experts write them themselves with Guvnor).

As for implementation in your database:

- Either apply the credit rules before you *save the sales record* in your business layer (server-side). If you got a 3 tier architecture (client - java server - database), this should be easy enough. You probably want to use a `StatelessSession` (but only instantiate your `KnowlegdeBase` once).
- Either flag the sales record with boolean `alreadyCreditChecked` `false`, send a signal to a separate process, which extracts those not yet checked and checks them.

Comment: Can Drools be used to read a table to determine what the rule condition will be?  For example, a certain sales person type gets a particular cap on a promotion, where the other sales person type has a much higher cap. Can Drools look up the sales person type and then use that cap in the rule?

Comment: From duffymo's correspondence, I have determined that the answer to my above question is no, Drools needs all record data on hand, up-front to work the rule. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it can. Look into the hibernate integration.

Comment: But if it's not to much data, I 'd load it beforehand, so you avoid any n+1 query problems as well as give drools's RETE algorithm a change to optimize a lot.